# Imported entries showing wrong post date

Tags: entries

Anyone familiar with InstaBlog plugin? I need to import some entries (not Wordpress) and everything works fine except the published date for all entries is showing today's date. When I view the entries in the control panel, the post date for each entry is correct, but is displaying the wrong date on front end. The InstaBlog template uses this to display the dates

`<div itemprop="datePublished">{{ blog.postDate.format('F d, Y') }}</div>`

Has anyone encountered this?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [date Twig filter](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/date.html) instead

`{{ entry.postDate|date( 'F d, Y' ) }}`

If the post dates on your entries are stored as datetime objects then the above should work.